# How to add new bone to existing rig?

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, bones

I have rigged model and want to add some new bones to it. But when I add them, they do not affect the mesh, unlike the rest of the bones, which they are children of. How do I make the new bones affect the mesh too?

This forum already has similar topics, but there are no answers in them.

Comment: either with a brush in Weight Paint mode, or with the Assign button in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups

Comment: @moonboots Thanks for the answer!
I created a new vertex group from the part of the body that the new bone should affect on, but I don't know what to do next. Can you tell me, please? I've never heard of this method before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let say you've parented your mesh to the armature, *With Automatic Weight* for example, and that you've created a new bone called arm_L.

Select the part of the mesh that this bone is supposed to affect, go in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups*, create a new group called arm_L and click on the *Assign* button to assign these vertices to this group. If the group has the exact same name as the bone, the bone will automatically influence this vertex group.

Note that on the right of the vertex groups list you have additional functions.

Another method is the Weight Painting, you can't always count on it though.

[image]

Comment: Thank's a lot! You really helped me out.